# Micro SD Card Not Detecting

Tags: sd-card, encryption

I am Using a Android phone Sony Z3 (5.0 - Lollipop), the Issue is My SD Card My Micro SD Card is not detecting in mobile and PC

Let me tell u clearly what i have done step by step?

1. Encryption (Phone & SD Card)
2. Factory Reset the Phone
3. Again Encryption but this time i didn't find the option of Encrypt SD Card. so only phone encrypt completed.

I tried to find the files in SD then i realize my SD is not detected then tried to put in pc its asking to format.

Please suggest i have backup in SD.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid your back up SD data cannot be read. Reasons

- On doing factory reset your , [encryption keys are lost](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/55837/20150527/androids-factory-reset-does-not-wipe-your-data-heres-the-solution.htm). Which includes encryption of your external SD card and without this keys, possible to access contents.   Quoting from linked source (which incidentally advocates this method (encryption + Factory Reset ) as keeping information away from buyers, if you sell your phone)

> Encrypting does not completely delete the files, but the factory reset process gets rid of the encryption key. As a result, the device has no way it can decrypt the files and, therefore, makes data recovery extremely difficult.

- Even assuming that you had an unencrypted SD card and wanted to fix the problem of not being able to read it, the very fact that neither your phone not PC can read it makes it nearly impossible to obtain data. You can still try to diagnose using this useful flowchart https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/external-sd/info. This is more for information and structured way of diagnosing SD card issues